# How can a "rip-off" still be good?

Tags: creative-writing, technique

This time, I'm not really talking about the legal side (that has already been covered a few times here), but more about what the readers and the critics think.

The Inheritance Cycle rips off Star Wars, Lord of the Rings. And although many people love it, some critics have expressed a disdain (in a very unprofessional, as far as evidence is concerned, way) towards it.

So apparently, you can still make something good from a bunch of stolen things, however, it conflicts with [what Amadeus said about good stories](https://writing.stackexchange.com/a/32836/25507):

> The answer to that is much harder work than becoming a good technical writer: You have to invent a good original story with something about it people (most of them) have not fully imagined before. Before JK Rowling, I would not have thought of a Wizard's school that would appeal to a children's audience. Before Dan Brown, I would not have thought of Christian artifacts, statues, buildings and manuscripts of having hidden clues to a major secret being covered up by the Vatican. Both of those are genius ideas, superb stories imperfectly realized.

These two contradict each other, and one of them is somewhat true and the other is factual.

So, even going against what's been established of popular but not perfectly executed stories, The Inheritance Cycle still manages to be popular. **How did it do that and how can I replicate the trick?**

Comment: Well the obvious and unrelated question is: why would you want to? Are you suggesting you can't come up with even a partially-original story? Sure, most everything has been done before, but you can at least re-imagine the old cliches in a different light if nothing else.

Comment: @ThomasMyron Well, I'm not sure, and that's already been done with trope aversion, inversion, de-; and reconstructions, justification, and exaggeration. Name it, I've seen it.

Comment: @LameZeldaPun Long history of 'there are only seven stories' if I don't miss my mark.

Comment: Notice one thing about *Harry Potter* - it is not actually that original a story, but people **think** it's original because it's original enough. By that I mean, so many stories feature a child who feels out of place and miserable and then is suddenly granted a magical opportunity to turn their whole life around. *Cinderella* and *Charlie and the Chocolate Factory* come to mind. So it's a subtle thing. Why is *Harry Potter* accepted as original (and *Star Wars* for that matter, which lifted heavily from a Japanese movie)?

Comment: The Brothers Grimm seemed to do OK at this.

Comment: Related: [The seven basic plots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Seven_Basic_Plots)

Comment: If you want an even more clear example of a successful rip-off, take a look at Lev Grossman's *The Magicians*. He never really hid the fact that it was a Narnia rip-off: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/5448/what-is-the-relationship-between-fillory-and-narnia

Comment: I don't understand this quote at all. Magical schoolchildren is a very common trope, and the Vatican / Illuminati is also another very common trope. Ironically, one of Dan Brown's biggest criticisms (and even legal challenges) is the notion that he [may have ripped off The DaVinci Code](https://www.marketwatch.com/story/dan-brown-faces-possible-new-plagiarism-lawsuit-over-the-da-vinci-code-2017-10-18)

Comment: Dan Brown just wrote a fictional story around _Holy Blood, Holy Grail_. Star Wars is basically The Hidden Fortress. (As @ToddWilcox mentioned). A Fistful of Dollars is an American remake of Yojimbo. Lion King is Hamlet, with lions. Romeo and Juliet is Pyramus and Thisbe. Most of art is interpreting certain re-occurring themes and motifs, but rather than going over what I think of that I'm just going to scroll down and read Mark's answer.

Comment: I was watching Back to the Future recently, and I thought to myself...  they used a lot of Jules Vern's ideas and references. It just so happened that he wrote something about time travel, and the trilogy is entirely about time travel. So, you can say it's a bit of a rip-off of the original author, but with a fan-based twist.

Comment: @DavidK Was Narnia littered with adult themes? I've been watching the TV Series, one of the female leads becomes extremely powerful by chugging a bucket of ejaculate from a male god. Both homosexual and heterosexual sex abounds, as well as drunken group sex, references to fellatio, cunnilingus, bondage, and rough anal sex. I did not read the books, or Narnia, but I think we can safely say The Magicians contains original elements (for a fantasy) to appeal to the 18+ young adults. Am I mistaken? Are those in Narnia?

Comment: @Amadeus No, clearly not - Narnia was written as a Christian allegory for children - but that's the point. To make a "rip-off" successful you need to do something different enough to make your story unique. The changes don't even have to be significant enough that you can't tell where you got the idea from, but they do need to be interesting enough to make your reader want to read your version anyway.

Comment: @DavidK Welp, they say that Narnia is basically just the retelling of the Bible with lion Jesus and Elsa's evil clone as Satan.

Comment: @LameZeldaPun Interestingly, C.S. Lewis argues that the books are *not* an allegory, but instead a "suppositional" ([Wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Religion_in_The_Chronicles_of_Narnia))

Comment: If you are looking for an "original" idea, I don't think tales about a wizarding retirement home have been fleshed out yet.

Comment: "Your manuscript is both good and original; but the part that is good is not original, and the part that is original is not good." -- attributed to Mark Twain

Comment: The Worst Witch(1974), The Dark Is Rising(1965), Groosham Grange (1988) are all examples of books which carry similar tropes and precede Harry Potter.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I think you're taking the wrong lesson from Amadeus' post. There were any number of kids' books about magic schools before Rowling, and the idea of secret conspiracies at the Vatican probably is as old as the Vatican itself.  For that matter, *The Lord of the Rings* is founded heavily on old myths, and *Star Wars* is basically a fairy tale set in space.  So that evidence alone argues against the absolute necessity of a wholly original concept.

There's an oft-quoted aphorism of uncertain provenance to the effect that "good artists copy, great artists steal."  All artists and writers borrow from each other.  But [a derivative work](https://partiallyexaminedlife.com/2015/06/10/grossman-vs-lewis-a-trip-to-an-atheist-narnia) makes you think of the original, whereas [a great work](http://www.shakespeare-online.com/sources/romeosources.html) makes you forget it had any antecedents.

What makes the difference?  In my view, writing (or other arts) involves solving both technical and artistic problems.  Plot is largely a technical problem --there are certain structures that work, and others that don't.  And it's okay to imitate other people's solution of technical problems.  But every great work of art also solves some artistic problem, and those problems --and their solutions --is what makes a great work of art truly unique.  If your work doesn't have some artistic problem at its heart that it solves better than any other work ever did it, then people might as well skip your work entirely, and stick to the original.

Comment: More specifically for star wars: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sources_and_analogues

Answer (score 16):

The thing about originality is that originality is judged from the reader perspective.

### A reader will only consider a story a retread if it's similar to *one they already know*.

You see this effect particularly strongly in YA novels, because young children, almost by definition, tend to be less well read than adults.  Take, for example, the Inheritance Cycle.  The series takes the plot of Star Wars, the magic of Earthsea, adds a Pernese psychic dragon-bond, and drops it all on a bog-standard Tolkienesque fantasy world.  But the vast majority of the middle-schoolers who read the book have not read A Wizard of Earthsea, or the Dragonriders of Pern.  So True Name magic and psychic dragons are new and exciting, even though the ideas that inspired Paolini are decades old.

Now, many of the kids reading Eragon were probably familiar with Star Wars and Lord of the Rings.  But how new something seems depends on more than just familiarity with previous iterations of the same concept - it also depends on familiarity with other things.  A chihuahua and a poodle seem like totally different animals, until you put them in a lineup with a crocodile, an emu, and a walrus.  Suddenly it become apparent how similar they are in the grand scheme of things.  The same is true with stories.  For a child, Eragon is a new twist on the story they loved in Star Wars, and it's not until they start to read other versions of the Hero's Journey that it starts to become apparent how little twisting it actually does.

### The Familiar and the Strange

"The familiar and the strange" is a concept that I first encountered listening to the [Writing Excuses podcast](http://www.writingexcuses.com/).  The idea is that audiences need something that they can relate to, but they also need something new and interesting, and the key to keeping reader interest is to find the correct balance between the two.

The trick, though, is that every reader finds a different set of experiences familiar.  If you divide up Inheritance like I did above as a combination of Lucus, Tolkien, Le Guin, and McCaffery, then for me Paolini is a mix of familiar, familiar, familiar, familiar.  But his general audience finds this mix to be familiar, familiar, strange, strange.  It's a good mix for them, and a terrible one for me.  Meanwhile, the books that are a good mix of familiar and strange to me are going to lean heavily on strange to those kids.  (Also, kids are drawn to repetition, and their balance of how much strange vs how much familiar they want is different, just as how they measure strangeness is different)

Any book that does as well as Harry Potter, Inheritance, or The Da Vinci Code is necessarily drawing the majority of its audience from people with less familiarity with the existing literature that they're built off of.  That means that any book that hits the sweet spot of strangeness for millions of people is going to necessarily feel overly familiar to experienced readers.

### There's more too it, of course

If I had some sort of magic formula for writing world-famous stories, I would not be going to work tomorrow.  To be successful a story needs to tap into more than just a mediocre level of unfamiliarity.  But I think that this explains in part why so often *popularity* and *quality* seem to be, if not opposed then at least tangential to each other.

Comment: True Name magic is a lot older than Earthsea though.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons To me, and presumably to Arcanist Lupus, True Name magic will always be Earthsea magic. Doesn't matter whether it was original. That's where I first encountered it, so that's what I will always associate it with when I encounter it somewhere else.

Comment: @Arthur fair enough, but the basic idea of true name magic dates back at least to classical Antiquity, so I personally find it odd to see a 20th century book as the source.

Comment: @Orangesandlemons You're right. I didn't read that part of the answer as "This is where it's from" but rather "This is where I know it from", and responded to your comment with that in mind. On second read-through, it does sound a bit like the former, though.

Answer (score 12):

I am not convinced the Wizard's school is necessarily 'new' any more than any other story. Rowling acknowledges the [Chronicles of Narnia as an influence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Potter_influences_and_analogues), and the '[boarding school trope](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BoardingSchool)' is (was) a staple in British literature, it fell out of favor in the 1960s according to the link.

Perhaps she mashed these together in a new way, but it never seemed so to me.

Narnia itself is also derived - from the story of Christ. Much in the Bible is likewise built on previous works, such as Genesis being a [creation myth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_creation_myths) patterned after others that came before it.

I was surprised elsewhere on the inter webs at the idea of a historical story of a vampire that did not wish to be made so, and how he lives to exact revenge on the vampire who made him. This idea and discussion was seemingly unaware of Anne Rice and LeStat (and Louis.)

**Why do stories re-cycle?**

These observations lead me to speculate that **we resurrect our mythologies anew for each generation.** (Zombies and vampires are now fading, because we just 'did those.')

**How can you be successful?**

**Write a story about a discotheque, and a flash dancer, and a chorus line.** :) Mash up all the dance stories that were en vogue in the 1970s and 1980s. They need to be trotted out again, for the next generation.

Comment: Your last paragraph actually sounds like excellent advice! I mean... no bad idea. Not worth the effort. Tell you what, I'll fall on my sword and write those stories and let you know how it turns out.

Comment: Make it good, @ToddWilcox we can use some toe-tapping music in this day and age!

Comment: If Narnia pleased audiences as well as Harry Potter, it would have sold 450 million copies, instead of 100 million copies. And it had about a forty year head start, and is still selling, and has also had movies (that did not earn as much). Perhaps you liked it better, but clearly a third of a billion people disagreed with you. Perhaps CS Lewis's word choices are too esoteric, or sentence structure, or social setting. Perhaps the centrality of the sport Quidditch speaks to children better in our sports obsessed world, or it's Hermione. Your argument dismisses the actual **results**.

Comment: @Amadeus Cheers, my efforts were clumsily geared around the idea of presence/lack of newness. "How can a **ripoff** still be good..."   I've edited my answer to clarify.

Answer (score 11):

Ah, the myth of originality. (Hi @LaurenIpsum! Waves.)

No one in the publishing industry wants originality. Not publishers. Not readers. The only people in the orbit of publishing that claim to value originality are snarky internet trolls and bad tempered newspaper columnists. And these people, of course, are the least original people in the whole system since complaining about lack of originality is the oldest (and cheapest) way of drawing attention to yourself by creating tempest in a teapot controversies.

Another industry that has no interest in originality is the fast food industry. When McDonalds or Wendy's introduces a new product, what is it? A slab of protein between two slabs of starch with some token roughage and a more or less spicy sauce. It is not original. It is a variation on a popular theme.

Random House and Penguin value originality about as much as McDonalds and Burger King do. Which is to say, not at all. Want to pitch your book? Tell me what other books it is like. And why? Because readers don't want originality. They want the same burger they had last time.

So why bother publishing new books at all? For the same reason that Burger King cooks new burgers every day. Because nobody wants stale burgers. What we want is not originality, but freshness. Hot off the presses; hot off the grill.

Books grow stale in a different way from hamburgers, but they do go stale. Their references grow outdated. The causes they pander to go out of fashion. The particular fad they belong to gets old. Out with the emo vampire lovers, in the with emo cowboy lovers! Would you like mustard or mayo on your burger?

Rowling did a masterful job or reheating the leftovers of a century and a half of English children's literature. There is everything in there from the long tradition of boarding school stories, to train stories, to magic stories. (If you want to know the roots of Harry Potter, read E Nesbit. It's all in there.) It's leftovers, but it is a masterful reheat, and if you didn't grow up eating those meals you would never know the difference.

If you want to be a successful author, don't even think about trying to be original. Think about making old stories fresh again. It is all about old wine in new skins. Same old plonk. Brand new label.

And there is nothing dishonorable or cynical about this. This has been the task of the storyteller from of old: to retell the old stories for a new generation. We preserve by remaking. Because without remaking, the old stories would become incomprehensible. Originality is not our job. Our job is faithful retransmission of the ancient tales of the primordial campfire. The essence of our craft is not originality, but freshness.

Comment: In writing, "Freshness" IS originality, in the sense it **has not** been done before. Again, this facile dismissal ignores the results. if Potter is a rehash of previous stories, Narnia or Nesbit or whomever, why did THEY not capture even an approximate equivalent for their time of 450 million copies sold and billions of dollars in sales? This first-time unknown writer worked on her novel for five years, plenty of time for better known authors that could command larger marketing budgets. They **failed** and she succeeded, with original writing buyers liked better and recommended to friends.

Comment: @Amadeus Your argument assumes that originality is the key to high sales volumes. It is not. It is not about the originality of the idea but about the freshness of the telling. The iphone was not an original idea. Why did Apple so vastly outsell Blackberry in the smartphone market? A fresh design and a pitch to a ripe market that Blackberry was not interested in serving.  You are arguing popular, therefore original. Nothing in the marketplace bears out that argument. Packaging and timing is 98% of that game. BTW, have you read E Nesbit?

Comment: And the iphone has several original (and patented) components that prove that "freshness" of design was the result of originality. The single button was original, the ease of use was original, the organization of the interface was original. Outside of the realm of food in which "fresh" is the opposite of "stale", **products** are "fresh" because they include something original, that has not been done before, and is therefore interesting or more functional or more fun or easier to use or more powerful. New characters or new plot details in an old plot are original. Buffy TVS was original.

Comment: @Amadeus Again you are arguing that all differences constitute originality. You can if you like, but you are bending the language to fit your argument rather than addressing the issues at stake. What matters is what kinds of differences, in what domain, led to the success you are studying. Merely saying "originality" tells us nothing.

Comment: No I am not. As I said before, even massive changes to names and setting and language could still constitute a pale imitation. What constitutes "originality" is differences **that make the work wildly more popular**, because the only plausible argument for that is these differences deliver something the audience loves in the new work that audiences **did not find** in the previous work. I think you are bending the meaning of "original" by pretending something can be "fresh" without adding anything "original". The changes that caused the massive appeal had their **origin** in the author's mind.

Comment: @Amadeus, which puts you right back to saying that the definition of original is popular. Again, such a definition of original is useless for our purposes since it amounts to saying that the way to be popular is to be popular. Arguing about whose definition of the word wins is not productive. What we need is a way to discuss which factors make works popular. Saying popular because original and original because popular contributes nothing to that discussion.

Comment: You cannot dismiss the qualifiers. Merely popular is not proof of originality, but massively popular and record-breaking **does** prove it contains something original and heretofore unseen, and that **does** help readers by letting them analyze the story to **understand** what was original that caused such **massive** appeal. Because if it was a technique, like being better at getting into the heads of adolescents, that can be repeated in a different kind of story, like a modern day non-magical adventure. Pretend there was **nothing** original and that opportunity to analyze is lost.

Comment: @Amadeus " but massively popular and record-breaking does prove it contains something original" It would prove, in any case, that it contains something *perceived* as original and marketed the *right* way so you notice it is there. Whether it is actually original or not can't be extrapolated by sales figures and/or reaction, but with that level of reaction it can be assured that it is *perceived* as original ('cause we humans like shiny new things (even when they are not actually shiny and/or new))

Comment: The problem with originality is that if someone really wants a burger, you're going to find it difficult to sell them a salad.

Answer (score 2):

This does answer the OP's question: As I said in my answer, and added P.S. and P.P.S, and comments later, the only requirement is that something (significant) be original, which can include characters, plot, setting, etc.

Superficial generalities of Rowling's work versus others does not change the fact that she DID have original characters, her own plot, and writing accessible to an adolescent market. There is a reason she has sold more than all that went before her, literally billions of dollars worth of entertainment, and that is not luck: The ones to which she is "similar" obviously failed to captivate a billion dollar audience, they published years before her (she worked on her novel for five years).

As I explained in the earlier answer, you cannot market your way to selling on the order of half a billion copies of anything; 85% of that market **will not buy** just because an ad tells them too if critics and other readers are saying the work is crap. The only way to sell 450 million copies is if they are reliably pleasing to the intended audience, in her case both adolescents AND their parents as suitable reading material.

The fact that Narnia did not do the same is all the proof you need that Rowling did not just rip off Narnia and do it again, she may have been inspired by Narnia, or mythology, or history, but she simply must have done something **original** with that inspiration that made her work **better** in the eyes of the audience than Narnia. To think otherwise is ludicrously implausible.

The answer is, yes, you can be inspired by Star Wars, or Rowling, or Stephen King, or Dan Brown, but you need to bring something original and compelling to the story in order to not be reviewed as a pale imitation of the master. You need original characters, OR setting, OR a connection to current social issues, OR a plot the original has not used, OR just plain better and more immersive portrayals than the original.

Because few publishers will purchase a novel, and few people will buy, a book that is routinely panned as virtually identical to The Da Vinci Code with different names for the characters.

My answer, with the P.S. and PPS and comments, stands as written.

Comment: I almost jumped on the earlier answer with examples of previous work (Jill Murphy, anyone?), but you're right - the answer stood as this one stands, and I knew I was just taking parts of it out of context. [Funny, though - I still can't entirely resist seeing a sentence that includes the words "Dan Brown" and "master" as bait...]

Comment: @ItWasLikeThatWhenIGotHere First, thanks for having a name longer than 15 characters, it helps a lot with circumventing SE's defenses, second, I think that feeling of yours has something to do with the author in question being the namer of an inaccuracy trope, with a [whole page of examples](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/DanBrowned/DanBrown) dedicated to him.

Comment: @LameZeldaPun - no circumvention intended, and I'm already a bit too guilty of considering the phrase "excrement is brown" as a commutative operation. As such, it's good when people remind me - as Amadeus did when taken in context - of what Dan does well.

Comment: Rowlink produced a pastiche of pretty much the entire cannon of English children's literature going back as far as E Nesbit and JM Barrie. That is, in itself, a work of a kind of genius. This is not to say that there is no invention in HP. It is full of invention, but the invention consists of variations on a hundred themes. It weakness is not lack of invention but its tendency to pander, both to popular social tropes and to the childish desire to be "special".

Comment: @MarkBaker Then "pandering" is her invention? Gosh, why didn't anybody else think of that and make a billion dollars? Or maybe that's just a pejorative term for developing **original characters** that appeal to a modern audience. And it seems to me that both "popular social tropes" and "childish desires" should not be disdained but embraced for an author that explicitly writes to appeal to modern parents and adolescents, because obviously she correctly predicted it is what they wanted, and as it turns out, more than any other adolescent novel in history.

Comment: @Amadeus No, most popular authors pander. All politicians pander. Again you are arguing popular, therefore original. But that is hardly ever true of anything. Superior execution of the familiar and expected is what sells volumes. The characters in HP are not original. Nor should they be. They are embodiments of ancient archetypes that are embedded in our culture and our psyche. That is not a criticism. That is an author's job.

Comment: @MarkBaker Not exactly: I am arguing "original" because **record breaking** popularity by such a large factor proves the new work has something in it that its *similar* predecessors lacked, and that is not "marketing" because it is true even when the *similar* works are by world renown writers that sold tens of millions of copies. I am saying the idea that this magnitude of popularity is due to chance is such a ridiculous premise you and I would never write it in fiction; that something unique to the new work (and therefore original in it) is responsible for that magnitude of success.

Comment: @Amadeus yes, the new work had something in it that the others did not, but if you are going to argue that any difference constitutes originality then you are devaluing the word. Our task here is to discern what we need to do to be successful writers. Write something different from other writers, while technically true, is not helpful. If we want to talk usefully about what contributes to literary success we need a more confined definition of original than merely different. And we need a definition that allows for other properties to be examined and their relative importance weighed.

Comment: @MarkBaker My definition is actionable, and not "merely different". Invent new characters that will appeal strongly to your desired audience. Invent plot details easy for your audience to follow. If you write for modern adolescents, have your fiction reflect what their parents want to teach them and your humor, adventures, and the character's worries and relationships reflect the innocence of their age group. IMO your position, that there is **nothing** original about record-breaking blockbusters, so just write "freshened" recyclings and hope for the best, doesn't help aspiring writers either.

Comment: @Amadeus My position was never that there is nothing original about bestsellers. My position is that originality was not their outstanding virtue, and that the pursuit of originality as the preminet virtue of a story will only lead writers away from the main vein of story which flows in the human psyche. Excellence of execution, not originality of concept, is what will get you on the best seller lists.

Comment: Hi, Amadeus, I finally found this video that perhaps can tell what made Harry Potter so successful, here's the [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rq-9BnHPjsY&feature=youtu.be&t=1536).

Comment: It hardly seems to me that Rowling or Brown reached the best seller list through "excellence of execution", their stories are not (IMO) that expertly executed. As Stephen King says, Rowling never met an adverb she didn't like. Brown is routinely panned for poor writing. What gets people on the bestseller list is not "excellence of execution" but writing something new and delightfully entertaining to their audience, which mere imitation will not accomplish.

Comment: @LameZeldaPun The link seems plausible, that HP stories are really mysteries in a fantasy setting. If this is indeed what makes them the bestselling fiction of all time, then that notion is something copyable without really being derivative of HP. A mystery in a Western, or scifi, or King Arthur setting. I would have to know much more about this genre to know if this is a reasonable candidate for her originality; I don't read or write much for adolescents.